# use Canvas background color is strange on android

Tags: android, canvas

[image]

Hello, I want draw Text on GLSurfaceView on android.

so , I use Canvas, Bitmap and Paint

GLText method

```
public void GLText() {
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Canvas mCanvas;
    Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(128, 128, config);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(0);

    mCanvas.drawColor(0x00ffffff);

    Paint Pnt = new Paint();

    Pnt.setColor(0xffffffff);
    Pnt.setTextSize(10);
    Pnt.setAntiAlias(false);
    Pnt.setTextScaleX(1);

    mCanvas.drawText("test", 0, 20, Pnt);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mBitmap, 0);

    mBitmap.recycle();
}
```

and call `glText()` is `onDrawFrame`
onDrawFrame method is always execute.

I want remove background color.
this picture camera preview display.

thanks.

Comment: remove `mBitmap.eraseColor(7);` line and try

Comment: Since you are drawing color on canvas using `mCanvas.drawColor(0x00ffffff);` then why are you doing `mBitmap.eraseColor(0);`, it is unnecessary. And since you are doing `mCanvas.drawColor(0x00ffffff);`, the background will be transparent. So the reason behind the background color is you are placing that bitmap above some **View** with background.

Comment: so, `mBitmap.eraseColor(0);` delete?

Comment: yeah since you are drawing on bitmap's canvas, you can delete that

Comment: uh.. i try `eraseColor` delete. but same problem..